# What autocomplete jQuery plugins is the easiest to use for rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, autocomplete

I need a simple and flexible autocomplete jQuery plugin. In your experience, which jQuery plugin has the best performance and flexibility?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either the jQuery-ui autocomplete
http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

or the autocomplete plugin
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete

Comment: I am struggling to get the json to load properly. I can't figure out how to check, but nothing is coming back

Answer (score 1):

The one in the jQuery-ui works great for me:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/